# 0x003baf00 scalar deleting destructor' unsigned int

Tags: visual-c++

I'm building a game in c++. I have a class called eggAI and a socket listener running in a thread. On socket reception, the egg moves forward. So I'm creating an instance of the eggAI class and moving it forward (because the socket listener function have to be static). Here is what to do on socket reception

```
eggAI *mn = new eggAI();
mn->bMoveForward(true);
```

My game is running but the egg isn't moving on socket reception. I tried to debug and found that the problem is in mn->bMoveForward(true), the debug showed me **0x003baf00 scalar deleting destructor' (unsigned int)**. Note that in eggAI.h, I have defined a constructor and a destructor and in eggAI.cpp, I have implemented them:

//eggAI.h

```
#ifndef __eggAI_h__
#define __eggAI_h__
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "S3DX/S3DXAIModel.h"
#include "chasing_the_egg_Plugins.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <winsock2.h>    
#include <process.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S3DX_DECLARE_AIMODEL( eggAI )
{
public:

    // Handlers:
    // 
    S3DX_DECLARE_HANDLER( onInit );
    S3DX_DECLARE_HANDLER( onMouseMove );
    S3DX_DECLARE_HANDLER( onEnterFrame );
    S3DX_DECLARE_HANDLER( onCaptureInput );
    S3DX_DECLARE_HANDLER( onKeyboardKeyUp );
    S3DX_DECLARE_HANDLER( onKeyboardKeyDown );

    // States:
    // 

    // Functions:
    // 
    void createHUD ( );
    void showMouse ( S3DX::AIVariable b = S3DX::nil );
    static unsigned __stdcall socketing (void *pi);
    void centerMouse ( );
    void createDynamic ( );
    void updateCharPos ( );
    void updateDynamics ( );
    static unsigned __stdcall direction (void *ea);
    eggAI();
    virtual ~ eggAI();

    // Variables:
    // 
    S3DX_DECLARE_VARIABLE( nSpeed );
    S3DX_DECLARE_VARIABLE( hDynObj );
    S3DX_DECLARE_VARIABLE( nGravity );
    S3DX_DECLARE_VARIABLE( bMoveBack );
    S3DX_DECLARE_VARIABLE( nCurAngleH );
    S3DX_DECLARE_VARIABLE( nCurAngleV );
    S3DX_DECLARE_VARIABLE( nDstAngleH );
    S3DX_DECLARE_VARIABLE( nDstAngleV );
    S3DX_DECLARE_VARIABLE( bMoveForward );
    S3DX_DECLARE_VARIABLE( bCaptureInput );
};
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif // __eggAI_h__
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

//eggAI.cpp

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "eggAI.h"
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Common AIModel implementation
//
S3DX_IMPLEMENT_AIMODEL( eggAI )
    eggAI::eggAI() { }
    eggAI::~eggAI() { }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// States mapping
//
S3DX_BEGIN_STATE_MAP( eggAI )
S3DX_END_STATE_MAP( eggAI )

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Event handlers mapping
//
S3DX_BEGIN_HANDLER_MAP( eggAI )
    S3DX_HANDLER( eggAI, onInit )
    S3DX_HANDLER( eggAI, onMouseMove )
    S3DX_HANDLER( eggAI, onEnterFrame )
    S3DX_HANDLER( eggAI, onCaptureInput )
    S3DX_HANDLER( eggAI, onKeyboardKeyUp )
    S3DX_HANDLER( eggAI, onKeyboardKeyDown )
S3DX_END_HANDLER_MAP( eggAI )

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Variables mapping
//
S3DX_BEGIN_VARIABLE_MAP( eggAI )
    S3DX_VARIABLE( eggAI, nSpeed, S3DX_VARIABLE_TYPE_NUMBER )
    S3DX_VARIABLE( eggAI, hDynObj, S3DX_VARIABLE_TYPE_OBJECT )
    S3DX_VARIABLE( eggAI, nGravity, S3DX_VARIABLE_TYPE_NUMBER )
    S3DX_VARIABLE( eggAI, bMoveBack, S3DX_VARIABLE_TYPE_BOOLEAN )
    S3DX_VARIABLE( eggAI, nCurAngleH, S3DX_VARIABLE_TYPE_NUMBER )
    S3DX_VARIABLE( eggAI, nCurAngleV, S3DX_VARIABLE_TYPE_NUMBER )
    S3DX_VARIABLE( eggAI, nDstAngleH, S3DX_VARIABLE_TYPE_NUMBER )
    S3DX_VARIABLE( eggAI, nDstAngleV, S3DX_VARIABLE_TYPE_NUMBER )
    S3DX_VARIABLE( eggAI, bMoveForward, S3DX_VARIABLE_TYPE_BOOLEAN )
    S3DX_VARIABLE( eggAI, bCaptureInput, S3DX_VARIABLE_TYPE_BOOLEAN )
S3DX_END_VARIABLE_MAP( eggAI )
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It seems like I'm missing something